# Como conecto google spreadsheets con la cotización de BITCOIN en Binance API?

Tags: javascript, api, script, binance

Estoy intentando escribir una script en google spreadsheets que traiga la cotizacion de BITCOIN de la API de Binance.

He realizado este script y funciona pero si lo uso un par de veces seguidas el servidor me banea unos minutos y me dice que lo haga con websockets.

[20-12-27 21:58:35:241 CET] https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT
[20-12-27 21:58:35:422 CET] {"code":-1003,"msg":"**Way too much request weight used; IP banned until 1609105477841. Please use the websocket for live updates to avoid bans.**"}

Alguien me puede indicar como hacerlo? o donde encontrar documentación para realizarla? El query que genera es este https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CRYPTO");
  
  var key = "oculta";
  var secret = "oculta";

  var baseURL = "https://api.binance.com";
  var completeURL  = baseURL + "/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT";
  var timestamp=new Date().getTime();
  var payload = "timestamp="+timestamp;
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(payload, secret);
  signature = signature.map(function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('');

  var params = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'X-MBX-APIKEY': key},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(completeURL, params);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
    
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(response[1]);
  
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Puedes empezar con la documentación de WebSocket para consumir la información de binance [aquí](https://docs.binance.org/api-reference/dex-api/ws-streams.html). El protocolo de WS es mucho más óptimo para lo que quieres desarrollar (además de que podrías recibir notificaciones en tiempo real, aunque esto último quizás desde una hoja de cálculo de Google sea más complicado).

Answer (score 0):

pasaba por acá y encontré el error. Resulta que Google utiliza un pool de IPS para hacer las consultas y están baneadas justamente por haber alcanzado el límite de consultas. Cambiando la variable baseurl a https://api1.binance.com/ se soluciona

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
from twisted.internet import reactor

 


client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
btc_price = {'error':False}

def btc_trade_history(msg):
    ''' define how to process incoming WebSocket messages '''
    if msg['e'] != 'error':
        print(msg['c'])
        btc_price['last'] = msg['c']
        btc_price['bid'] = msg['b']
        btc_price['last'] = msg['a']
    else:
        btc_price['error'] = True



bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)


# Iniciamos el websocket 

bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
conn_key = bsm.start_symbol_ticker_socket('BTCUSDT', btc_trade_history)
bsm.start()

# stop websocket

bm.stop_socket(conn_key)

# properly terminate WebSocket

reactor.stop()
```

Comment: WebSocket: Es una tecnología que proporciona un canal de comunicación bidireccional y full-duplex sobre un único socket TCP. Está diseñada para ser implementada en navegadores y servidores web, pero puede utilizarse por cualquier aplicación cliente/servidor. He hecho este video quizás te pueda servir https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-EK2d6rZyE

Comment: También les dejo esta guía de Binance que hice: "Guía de Binance API Python" https://moneytoday.es/guia-de-binance-api-python

Comment: ¿Por qué no editas tu respuesta e incluyes esos enlaces? Los comentarios pueden ser susceptibles de borrado.

Comment: En lo posible, indica brevemente qué hace este código. Recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta), sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Además, también haz un breve resumen de los enlaces que proporcionas: ten en cuenta que el contenido de los mismos puede que ya no esté disponible más adelante. Lee [answer].